# Changing from Theme.AppCompat to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar on runtime

Tags: android, themes, runtime, android-appcompat

I have a setting in my app where the user can change theme. The settings can be reached via a navigation drawer, and since I want to have a "hamburger menu icon" I've had to extend AppCompatActivity from my base activity.

My styles.xml is very simple:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

and my onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(MainActivityTransmit.this);
    Theme = sharedPreferences.getString("theme_preference","1");

    switch(Theme) {
        case "AppTheme":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            break;
        case "DarkTheme":
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_transmit);
```

Before, when I only extended Activity (and used the regular Material themes) this worked fine. However, now when I extend AppCompatActivity (and use the AppCompat themes) it doesn't work.

The text color changes depending on the theme I change to, but the background colors of both the screen and the actionbar stays the same as the one in the AndroidManifest (DarkTheme in my case).

Why is it suddenly different just because I use AppCompat and how do I fix it?

Comment: call the setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); before the super.OnCreate() method

Comment: I get another issue if I put it before the super.onCreate line though. I get a white bar above my actionbar. It is only present when I change to AppTheme though, not when I change to DarkTheme.

Comment: I solved it. The new problem disappeared when I changed the name of AppTheme to LightTheme instead. I have no idea why android behaved weirdly because of that name, but it did.